# Stacking two different views with different sizes on a layout

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, android-framelayout

I've searched for an answer for this all over but the solutions offered did not solve my problem.

I have a layout where I display some views (a few buttons and a background). To this i've added a custom control i've made extending linear layout. This control is displayed above the layout quite nicely.
What I wish to do is add an additional ImageView which is larger than this control but it will be in front of it.

edited: **Sorry, I hope this will clear things up.**

I have one large layout (Relative) for my activity, I would like to stack on this layout two additional views\layout so the final version will be the picture attached:

[image]

This is my layout - which stacks the imageview right on the menubar, and not over the others. Trying to put the FrameLayout elsewhere still didn't give me the wanted result.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
    <RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dip">
        <com.myproject.controls.SearchControl
            android:id="@+id/scSearch" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
        <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/lstItems"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/scSearch"
            android:layout_marginLeft="26dip"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.myproject.controls.MenubarMain
        android:id="@+id/mbMenuBarMain"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
    />
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/myicon"
                android:layout_width="200dip"
                android:layout_height="200dip"
                />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Nathan-fig sorry, i've added some concept images of what I want and what I get

Comment: Your question is not that clear. You simply added 2 images without any explanation. Just add a image with what you finally need. It might get you more answers.

Comment: Few questions: MenuBarMain is the blue right? and SearchControl the red? An ImageView goes inside of MenuBarMain? and is the ExpandableListView above the MenuBarMain in the white? or is it inside the SearchControl?

Comment: Hey, sorry for all the editing, please see revised picture. Hope it answers [Even if I remove the ExpandableListView and SearchControl I still get the same result].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it this will work or not cause I'm typing this up at work. But moral of the story here is get used to using RelativeLayout. You have much more control over your layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
    <com.myproject.controls.MenubarMain
        android:id="@+id/mbMenuBarMain"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </com.myproject.controls.MenubarMain>
    <com.myproject.controls.SearchControl
        android:id="@+id/scSearch" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </com.myproject.controls.SearchControl>
    <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/lstItems"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/scSearch"
        android:layout_above="@id/mbMenuBarMain"
        android:layout_paddingLeft="26dp"/>
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/myicon"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/mbMenuBarMain"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/mbMenuBarMain"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Amazing that all along it was such a simple answer.. It works! Thanks!